# Search for content in functions with regex

Tags: regex, recursion

How would I with regular expression search for functions which contains the use of a global variable without running "global $var" first?

The files looks like this:

```
class TestClass
{
    function correctFunc()
    {
        global $var;
        $name = $var->name;
    }

    function invalidFuncIWantToFind()
    {
        $age = $var->user->age;
    }
}
```

I want to find the function names of all the invalidFuncIWantToFind. At work this would have really speeded up our work but I didn't get how to do it.

Comment: Don’t use regular expressions when you’re processing a non-regular language like PHP.

Comment: if you want a quick&dirty&error-prone solution, regexes might work. if you want a stable solution you should look into parser generators for context free grammars (antlr.org for example). what kind of solution do you want?

Comment: I want a quick and dirty solution. :) I've continued to play with this and "function\s+(\w+).*?(\{.*?(\{.*?\})*.*?\})" seem to work to get all the functions. Now I just need to get those which contains "$var->" without first having "global $var;" Not sure how to do that though.

Comment: `$some_var = "{";` breaks your function-extracting regex. You should not use regex for it. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 - same holds for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Regex implementation, you might be able to use a lookbehind pattern for this. http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html claims that e.g. the .NET Framework implementation can do this. (Problematic is, that the lookbehind can contain a variable number of letters... this seems to cause trouble).
Since I do not have a Visual Studio at hand here, I cannot build a Regex for you, though, sorry.

Comment: Yes, I've been trying to do it with lookbehind but havn't got something working yet.